# How to display view in all available languages?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I need to set up a view that lists content in all available languages despite user's current language. I tried creating content translation relationships to all languages and setting fields to use these relationships, but it doesn't work. It only shows fields with the user's current language. How do I get it to list all fields in all languages?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The purpose of the language is exactly to show the content in the language the user prefers. I don't see the purpose of showing the content of all the fields in all the possible languages.

Comment: The purpose is not to show anything to users. I'm outputting the view as XML and I need to have all languages shown in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this with the field language setting in view.
I would try to set this to language neutral.

I have not tested this myself, just my 2 cents ;-)

Look to screenshots for clarification[image: Field Language settings][image: Field language is located under OTHER in views interface]

Comment: Already tried it. Does not work.